# How to calculate a ranking in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am designing a student management system, and I'm trying to design a report that represents a report card.

What I want to do is get a report that will display all the subjects and marks per student and the rank of the student based on the sum total marks of the subjects.

Here is an example of the information I would like to display:

```
Student  Physics  Chemistry  Total marks   Rank
  1      77       90             167       3
  2      90       98             188       1
  3      90       98             188       1
  4      48       80             128       4
```

I've used crosstab report, and I got all the subjects and marks per student and the total marks. Now I want to calculate the rank for each student based on total marks. How can I do that?

Comment: It might be easier to add the rank from the database side, are you using mysql, mssql etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done via the query fairly easily:

```
SELECT [Student],
  [Physics],
  [Chemistry],
  [Total_marks],
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Total_marks] DESC) AS Rank 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY [Student]
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39bc5/5/0)